# How do make this spacing?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

[image: mmm]

```
$ (E\mathcal{V}_{i+1})^{\perp}=(EA^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^T \stackrel{Lem. 1.1(i)}{=} E^{-T}(A^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}
  \stackrel{Lem. 1.1(ii)}{=} E^{-T}(A^T(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}=E^{-T}(A^T\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+1})=\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+2}$
```

I want to write as the picture. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add your complete MWE, please? What packages you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment and '\stackrel' macro
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth{\mylength}{\scriptsize Lem.\ 1.1(ii)}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(E\mathcal{V}_{i+1})^{\perp}
&\stackrel{\makebox[\mylength]{}}{=}
    (EA^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^T \\
&\stackrel{\makebox[\mylength]{\scriptsize Lem.\ 1.1(i)}}{=} 
    E^{-T}(A^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}\\
&\stackrel{\text{Lem.\ 1.1(ii)}}{=} 
    E^{-T}(A^T(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}\\
&\stackrel{\makebox[\mylength]{}}{=}E^{-T}
    (A^T\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+1})
    =\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you have a lot of these expressions, it's probably a good idea to set up a dedicated macro to represent the specialized `=` symbol, say along the lines of the following code (which generates the same output as the example shown above). If there's nothing to typeset above the `=` symbol, just write `\myeq{}` to get the spacing right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment and '\stackrel' macro
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth{\mylength}{\scriptsize Lem.\ 1.1(ii)} % width of  longest label
\newcommand\myeq[1]{\stackrel{\makebox[\mylength]{\scriptsize #1}}{=}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(E\mathcal{V}_{i+1})^{\perp}
&\myeq{}              (E A^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^T \\
&\myeq{Lem.\ 1.1(i)}  E^{-T}(A^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}\\
&\myeq{Lem.\ 1.1(ii)} E^{-T}(A^T(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}\\
&\myeq{}              E^{-T} (A^T\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+1})
     =\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `eqparbox`; the first argument to `\widerel` is an arbitrary label (different for each environment).

However, the second presented solution seems better. Of course, hard coding the lemma number is not recommended and `\ref` should be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\widerel}[2]{%
  \mathrel{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
(E\mathcal{V}_{i+1})^{\perp}
  &\widerel{A}{=}                                 (EA^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^T \\
  &\widerel{A}{\overset{\text{Lem.\ 1.1(i)}}{=}}  E^{-T}(A^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}\\
  &\widerel{A}{\overset{\text{Lem.\ 1.1(ii)}}{=}} E^{-T}(A^T(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}\\
  &\widerel{A}{=}                                 E^{-T}(A^T\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+1})
                                                  =\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+2}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
(E\mathcal{V}_{i+1})^{\perp}
  &= (EA^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^T \\
  &= E^{-T}(A^{-1}(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp} &&\text{Lemma 1.1(i)}\\
  &= E^{-T}(A^T(E\mathcal{V}_i))^{\perp}    &&\text{Lemma 1.1(ii)}\\
  &= E^{-T}(A^T\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+1})
     =\widehat{\mathcal{W}}_{i+2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are two solutions. The first one uses an `array` environment, with the equality signs going into a separate column. The second solution is the one I recommend, since it is better to read; it adds the justifications in an extra column instead of above the equality signs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcommand\VV{{\mathcal V}}
\newcommand\WW{{\mathcal W}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}l}
  (E\VV_{i+1})^{\perp}
  &=&(EA^{-1}(E\VV_i))^T\\
  &\stackrel{\text{Lem.1.1(i)}}{=}&E^{-T}(A^{-1}(E\VV_i))^{\perp}\\
  &\stackrel{\text{Lem.1.1(ii)}}{=}&E^{-T}(A^T(E\VV_i))^{\perp}\\
  &=&E^{-T}(A^T\widehat{\WW}_{i+1})\\
  &=&\widehat{\WW}_{i+2}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\VV{{\mathcal V}}
\newcommand\WW{{\mathcal W}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(E\VV_{i+1})^{\perp}
&=(EA^{-1}(E\VV_i))^T\\
&=E^{-T}(A^{-1}(E\VV_i))^{\perp} && \text{by Lem.~1.1(i)}\\
&=E^{-T}(A^T(E\VV_i))^{\perp} && \text{by Lem.~1.1(ii)}\\
&=E^{-T}(A^T\widehat{\WW}_{i+1})\\
&=\widehat{\WW}_{i+2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```